# Visual Studio 11 Beta... WPF template?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 11 Beta (Express for Windows 8) installed in my Windows 8 VM. When I press New Project, I can see a lot of templates for Metro apps... but nothing else. I can't find templates for making any sort of desktop application. In particular I would like to be able to make a WPF project in C#. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "Express for Windows 8" version only allows you to create Metro apps. From the [product page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh852659.aspx):

> You can use the tools in Visual Studio 11 Express Beta for Windows 8 to create Metro style apps for Windows 8. The tools include a fully featured code editor, a powerful debugger, a focused profiler, and rich language support that you can use to build apps that written in HTML5, JavaScript, C++, C# or Visual Basic. Visual Studio 11 Express Beta for Windows 8 also includes a device simulator that you can use to test Metro style apps on multiple form factors.

If you want to build other types of apps, you need to download the [beta of Visual Studio 11 Professional](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#professional). (I expect there'll probably be a plain "Visual C# Express 11" which allows for WinForms and WPF apps when it's non-beta... there's going to be a Release Candidate soon, so that may come with a suitable Express version.)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully you're right and it won't come to the point where I'll have to pay $ just to make a simple desktop application.

Comment: Heh. I remember when the Express editions started coming out in 2005. It was a huge deal, to be able to give hobbyists and students a free almost full-featured IDE. And now? Totally taken for granted.

Comment: I am thankful for all the technology Microsoft has given out for free. But, to me, there's something wrong with releasing free software, letting people (including small companies) establish their workflow on it, and then putting a price tag on it. This gives developers the option to just pay the money, or cling onto the old software until it's deprecated. I know other companies do this... but hopefully the things Microsoft started as free will be kept free.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: At least I'll still get to download VS11 Professional through DreamSpark :3